# Build fails with Fakes assembly

Tags: microsoft-fakes

I have a simple console application which has dependency to structuremap assemblies. I then added this console app reference to my test project and adding fakes assembly to it produces below error:

> Could not resolve assembly 'StructureMap, Version=2.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e60ad81abae3c223'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (TaskId:18)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fakes code generator relies on the assembly references in the test project when locating assemblies required to build the fakes assembly. Start by adding StructureMap as a reference to the test project. In Visual Studio 2012, on a rare occasion, you may also need to provide a project template with additional references. See the workaround section on the following page for details.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/782031/visual-studio-2012-add-fakes-assembly-does-not-add-all-needed-references

Comment: Your link is dead.